# D3 line graph with date slider

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a lines graph with a date slider from reading in data from a json file. Below is the json file.

Below is the html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- jQuery UI CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default"></nav>

        <!-- Bootstrap grid setup -->
        <div class="container">
            <div id="selections" class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div id="slider-div">
                        <label>Date: <span id="dateLabel1">12/05/2013</span> - <span id="dateLabel2">31/10/2017</span></label>
                        <div id="date-slider"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="chart-area"></div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- External JS libraries -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom JS -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

So far so good, I have been able to draw the line graphs, I will have the x axis as the date and the y axis being the AMOUNT and Running Total, I calculate the Y axis using the Running Total since that will be the bigger amount always.

Below is the D3.JS and here is where the problem is:

```
var margin = { left:80, right:100, top:50, bottom:100 },
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom, 
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;

var svg = d3.select("#chart-area").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + 
        ", " + margin.top + ")");

// Time parser for x-scale
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%d/%m/%Y");

//Transition time
var t = function(){ return d3.transition().duration(1000); }

// Scales
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// Axis generators
var xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom();
var yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft()
    .ticks(6)
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return "$" + d3.format(",.0f")(d);});
    //d3.format(",.0f")(d);
    //.tickFormat(function(d) { return parseInt(d / 1000) + "k"; });

// Axis groups
var xAxis = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
var yAxis = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")

var valueFiguresColour = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeSet1);

var valueFigures = ["Amount", "Running Total"];

var legend = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 120 +
        "," + 5 + ")");

valueFigures.forEach(function(values, i){
    var legendRow = legend.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (i * 20) + ")");

    legendRow.append("rect")
        .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("height", 10)
        .attr("fill", valueFiguresColour(values));

    legendRow.append("text")
        .attr("x", -10)
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .style("text-transform", "capitalize")
        .text(values);
});

var xLable = g.append("text")
    .attr("class", "x axis-label")
    .attr("x", width / 2)
    .attr("y", height + 50)
    .attr("font-size", "20px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Date ");

// Line path generator
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.DATE); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d["Running Total"]); });

var line2 = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.DATE); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.AMOUNT); });



// Add jQuery UI slider
$("#date-slider").slider({
    range: true,
    max: (parseTime("31/10/2018")),
    min: (parseTime("01/10/2018")),
    step: 86400000, // One day
    values: [(parseTime("01/10/2018")), (parseTime("31/10/2018"))],
    slide: function(event, ui){
        $("#dateLabel1").text(formatTime(new Date(ui.values[0])));
        $("#dateLabel2").text(formatTime(new Date(ui.values[1])));
        update();
    }
});


d3.json("data/test.json").then(function(data) {


    // Data cleaning
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.DATE = parseTime(d.DATE);
        d["Running Total"] = +d["Running Total"];
        d.AMOUNT = + d.AMOUNT;
    });

    // data.forEach(function(d) {
    //     console.log(d);
    // });

    // Set scale domains
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.DATE; }));
    y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d["Running Total"]; }) / 1.002, 
        d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["Running Total"]; }) * 1.002]);

    // Generate axes once scales have been set
    xAxis.call(xAxisCall.scale(x))
    yAxis.call(yAxisCall.scale(y))

    // Add line to chart
    g.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("fill", "grey")
        .style("stroke", "#377DB8")
        .attr("stroke-with", "8px")
        .attr("d", line(data));

    g.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke", "#E51A1D")
        .attr("stroke-with", "1px")
        .attr("d", line2(data));


        update();
});



function update(data) {

    // Filter data based on selections
    var sliderValues = $("#date-slider").slider("values");
    var dataTimeFiltered = data.filter(function(d){
        return ((d.DATE >= sliderValues[0]) && (d.DATE <= sliderValues[1]))
    });

    // Update scales
    x.domain(d3.extent(dataTimeFiltered, function(d){ return d.DATE; }));
    y.domain([d3.min(dataTimeFiltered, function(d){ return d["Running Total"]; }), 
        d3.max(dataTimeFiltered, function(d){ return d["Running Total"]; }) ]);


    // Update axes
    xAxisCall.scale(x);
    xAxis.transition(t()).call(xAxisCall);
    yAxisCall.scale(y);
    yAxis.transition(t()).call(yAxisCall.tickFormat(formatAbbreviation));


    // Path generator
    line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d){ return x(d.DATE); })
        .y(function(d){ return y(d.AMOUNT); });

    line2 = d3.line()
        .x(function(d){ return x(d.DATE); })
        .y(function(d){ return y(d["Running Total"]); });

    // Update our line path
    g.select(".line")
        .transition(t)
        .attr("d", line(dataTimeFiltered));

    g.select(".line")
        .transition(t)
        .attr("d", line2(dataTimeFiltered));
}
```

I do have the grpah showing the correct data and everything is in the right postion. The issue is I can't get my date slider to work and get the graph to update according the date slider. Anyone any suggestions? I have attached an image of what I have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few typos and you also need to setup your line classes.
The dates format also needed some adjusts, now it's all converted to number values.

The effect is not very nice but it's all working as expected.

```js
var margin = { left:40, right:40, top:40, bottom:80 },
    height = 240 - margin.top - margin.bottom, 
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right;

var svg = d3.select("#chart-area").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + 
        ", " + margin.top + ")");

// Time parser for x-scale
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%d/%m/%Y");
var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%d/%m/%Y");

//Transition time
var t = function(){ return d3.transition().duration(1000); }

// Scales
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// Axis generators
var xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom();
var yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft()
    .ticks(6)
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return "$" + d3.format(",.0f")(d);});

// Axis groups
var xAxis = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
var yAxis = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")

var valueFiguresColour = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeSet1);

var valueFigures = ["Amount", "Running Total"];

var legend = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 120 +
        "," + 5 + ")");

valueFigures.forEach(function(values, i){
    var legendRow = legend.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (i * 20) + ")");

    legendRow.append("rect")
        .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("height", 10)
        .attr("fill", valueFiguresColour(values));

    legendRow.append("text")
        .attr("x", -10)
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .style("text-transform", "capitalize")
        .text(values);
});

var xLable = g.append("text")
    .attr("class", "x axis-label")
    .attr("x", width / 2)
    .attr("y", height + 50)
    .attr("font-size", "20px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Date ");

var startDate = new Date(parseDate("05/10/2018")).valueOf();
var endDate = new Date(parseDate("23/10/2018")).valueOf();



// Add jQuery UI slider
$("#date-slider").slider({
    range: true,
    min: startDate,
    max: endDate,
    step: 86400000, // One day
    values: [startDate, endDate],
    slide: function(event, ui){
        $("#dateLabel1").text(formatTime(new Date(ui.values[0])));
        $("#dateLabel2").text(formatTime(new Date(ui.values[1])));
        update(data);
    }
});


var data = [
    {"DATE":"2018-10-05","AMOUNT":1.000000000000000e+002,"Running Total":1.000000000000000e+002},
    {"DATE":"2018-10-06","AMOUNT":1.000000000000000e+003,"Running Total":1.100000000000000e+003},
    {"DATE":"2018-10-07","AMOUNT":5.000000000000000e+003,"Running Total":6.100000000000000e+003},
    {"DATE":"2018-10-08","AMOUNT":2.000000000000000e+003,"Running Total":8.100000000000000e+003},
    {"DATE":"2018-10-09","AMOUNT":1.000000000000000e+003,"Running Total":9.100000000000000e+003},
    {"DATE":"2018-10-10","AMOUNT":5.000000000000000e+003,"Running Total":1.410000000000000e+004},
    {"DATE":"2018-10-11","AMOUNT":3.000000000000000e+003,"Running Total":2.510000000000000e+004},
    {"DATE":"2018-10-12","AMOUNT":1.200000000000000e+004,"Running Total":3.710000000000000e+004},
    {"DATE":"2018-10-13","AMOUNT":5.000000000000000e+003,"Running Total":4.210000000000000e+004},
    {"DATE":"2018-10-17","AMOUNT":1.300000000000000e+004,"Running Total":5.510000000000000e+004},
    {"DATE":"2018-10-18","AMOUNT":1.500000000000000e+004,"Running Total":7.010000000000000e+004},
     {"DATE":"2018-10-19","AMOUNT":2.500000000000000e+004,"Running Total":8.010000000000000e+004},
     {"DATE":"2018-10-20","AMOUNT":1.600000000000000e+004,"Running Total":5.010000000000000e+004},
     {"DATE":"2018-10-21","AMOUNT":1.800000000000000e+004,"Running Total":7.010000000000000e+004},
     {"DATE":"2018-10-22","AMOUNT":1.900000000000000e+004,"Running Total":9.010000000000000e+004},
     {"DATE":"2018-10-23","AMOUNT":3.500000000000000e+004,"Running Total":7.010000000000000e+004}
];
  // Data cleaning
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.DATE = parseTime(d.DATE);
    d["Running Total"] = +d["Running Total"];
    d.AMOUNT = +d.AMOUNT;
});
 
// Set scale domains
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.DATE; }));
y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d["Running Total"]; }) / 1.002, 
    d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["Running Total"]; }) * 1.002]);

// Generate axes once scales have been set
xAxis.call(xAxisCall.scale(x))
yAxis.call(yAxisCall.scale(y))

// Path generator
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d){ return x(d.DATE); })
  .y(function(d){ return y(d.AMOUNT); });
  
var line2 = d3.line()
  .x(function(d){ return x(d.DATE); })
  .y(function(d){ return y(d["Running Total"]); });
  
// Add line to chart
g.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr('fill', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke", "#E51A1D")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
    .attr("d", line(data));

g.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line2")
    .attr("fill", "rgba(0,0,0,0)")
    .style("stroke", "#377DB8")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
    .attr("d", line2(data));

update(data);


function update(data) {

    // Filter data based on selections
    var sliderValues = $("#date-slider").slider("values");
    
    var dataTimeFiltered = data.filter(function(d){
        return ((d.DATE >= sliderValues[0]) && (d.DATE <= sliderValues[1]))
    });

    // Update scales
    x.domain(d3.extent(dataTimeFiltered, function(d){ return d.DATE; }));
    y.domain([0, 
        d3.max(dataTimeFiltered, function(d){ return d["Running Total"]; }) ]);



    // Update axes
    xAxisCall.scale(x);
    yAxisCall.scale(y);
    
    // Update our line path
    g.select(".line")
        .transition(t)
        .attr("d", line(dataTimeFiltered));

    g.select(".line2")
        .transition(t)
        .attr("d", line2(dataTimeFiltered));
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- jQuery UI CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default"></nav>

        <!-- Bootstrap grid setup -->
        <div class="container">
            <div id="selections" class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div id="slider-div">
                        <label>Date: <span id="dateLabel1">05/10/2018</span> - <span id="dateLabel2">23/10/2018</span></label>
                        <div id="date-slider"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="chart-area"></div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- External JS libraries -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks man! I'm surpised! What were some of the errors? I was looking at it for so long I couldn't spot it.
Also I figured out to make the smooth transiton on axis, the code you need is:

    // Update axes
    xAxisCall.scale(x);
    xAxis.transition(t()).call(xAxisCall);
    yAxisCall.scale(y);
    yAxis.transition(t()).call(yAxisCall);

Comment: Also, how would I go about reading my data in from a json file to get this to work? I've tried adding in my json file but it's not reading in the data from other parts of the code? Maybe somehow make json the data public? Sorry man, I'm a noob at JS and D3

Comment: You are welcome! I edited your code to make the JSON an inline variable. Your code seems to fetch the data correctly. If you are having trouble with the XHR, you should open another question. If you wanna test the loading process you can use http://myjson.com/ to store you data publicly.